# Encounter format trouble in concatenating String

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

The file format is look like

```
abc def 
    ghy jk
          lmp
```

And here is my code

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader("./test.txt");
string afterreplace = "";
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    afterreplace = String.Concat(afterreplace, line); 
}
Console.WriteLine(afterreplace);
```

However I got this in my output

It doesn't match the original file

```
abc def     ghy jk      lmp
```

Of cause I can add some newline character, I really want to know why it cause

Does `String.Concat()` ignore the `\n`? How could I achieve my expectation?

Comment: "Does `String.Concat` ignore the `/n`?": No, but `ReadLine` doesn't include the newline.

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: I fix my code, it indeed caused by ReadLine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `string.Concat` that's doing that, it's `file.ReadLine()`. But you don't notice that in your output directly, because `Console.WriteLine` adds an extra newline.

From [StreamReader.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> **Remarks**
>
> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). ***The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed.*** [...]